# php file operations permission denied

Tags: php, apache, file-permissions, virtualhost

I have two Virtual Hosts on Redhat Enterprise server, one of which functions as desired.  The second I a have problems when using PHP to do any kind of file operations.  As far as I can tell both virtual hosts have been set up in the same.  I have checked that file permissions have been set correctly on the folders/files in question.  I have gone as far to set permissions to 777.

Can anyone suggest where I might have gone wrong? The virtual hosts are set up as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName intranet
 ServerAlias intranet *.intranet
 DocumentRoot /home/burnside/public_html
 <Directory "/home/burnside/public_html">
     allow from all
     Options +Indexes
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName tracker
 ServerAlias tracker *.tracker
 DocumentRoot /home/tracker/public_html
 <Directory "/home/tracker/public_html">
      Allow from all
      Options +Indexes
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The vhost has nothing to do with PHP's file permissions. You need to post the relevant error including the permissions of the file/folder it's occurring on.

Comment: You need to configure PHP in such a way that you can see the error messages (either by printing them or by logging them). Otherwise, you'll be just guessing.

Comment: Chances are you are using an incorrect path in the broken code. You'll need to post the PHP code before the problem can be found.

Comment: Permissions are all set to 777.  It is on any kind of file operation in this virtual host - anyway an example as requested:  Warning: file_put_contents(/home/tracker/application/var/graphs/chart.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/burnside/packages/...

Comment: You want user `burnside` to write inside `tracker` home directory. That's probably disallowed by SELinux.

Comment: Thank you, Alvaro - will do a bit of Googling along those lines.